Can't fix EPERM error on open of Evernote in Windows 11
After working properly for almost a year, my Windows 11 computer developed two problems at the same time. I list them both because I think they may be related.
The first problem was that my work account somehow became connected to this (personal) computer and locally-installed Office 365 apps stopped working. That seemed relatively straightforward and I believe I have fixed that.
The second problem that started happening at the same time was that my local Evernote app stopped working. I can get into my web account without incident. I tried installing a new version and that seemed to work. When  I tried to open it, however, I got an error. The error is:
Configuration File Error
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Evernote\config.json
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open
'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Evernote\config.json'
I tried uninstalling Evernote and reinstalling. But I keep getting this message when I tried to launch it. It's the only application, that I've found, that gives this error.
I've looked online, on the Evernote support, and on Stack Exchange, but can't find anything that seems to target this.
